# bootstrap datetimepicker error

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap datetimepicker control in angular.

I am getting below error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.locale is not a function

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.47/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/select2-bootstrap.css"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" rel="stylesheet">    

<script src="./js/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="./js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="./js/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker@4.17.47/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Here is the script code.

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
});



<div class="control-group">
        <label for="date-picker-2" class="control-label">B</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="date-picker-2" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
                <label for="date-picker-2" class="input-group-addon btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>

                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any advise what am i doing wrong?

Comment: if you use Angular it is better to use libraries for Angular. Here is reference for datepicker for Angular
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/datepicker

Comment: let me check. i will update you.

Comment: What is the version of the moment.min.js ?

Comment: @Ironic was your issue solved or still need help?

Comment: @NarenMurali still trying to solve it. Not yet solved.